# How can I monitor HTTP Outbound Connection Pool Usage in Websphere 6?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, connection-pooling, webservice-client

I have an application running on Websphere Application Server 6.1 and I changed the value of the following parameter to solve a performance problem.

`'com.ibm.websphere.webservices.http.maxConnection'`

Now I'm trying to monitor the usage of this pool, but I couldn't find any PMI measure to do so. Is there any way to gather this pool usage metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/WebSphere_Application_Server-WAS_Traditional-Web_Services.html

The outbound connection cache does not have PMI monitoring but does have a lightweight monitor trace:
JAX-RPC
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.channel.Monitor=all=enabled
JAX-WS
com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.channel.Monitor=all=enabled

Comment: I found that the problem was exactly the monitor trace instead of the connection pool. The synchronized log was preventing simultaneous request to create new connections. Anyway, your answer is correct.